# jQuery hover - Whats wrong with my 'mouseout' script?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make a fairly simple navigation for a number of pictures on a page. When the image is 'mouseover' I want the image itself to be 'greyed out' and panel to slide in from the right with some additional details.

This I managed to do with the following jQuery.

Now, what I want is, when the mouse leaves the image, to show the image clearly with slid panel slides backed out.

The strange thing is none of the jquery I tried to use (like fadeOut) are working at all. Here is my script:

**html**

```
 <div id="home_1" class="home_but">
    <div class="home_overlay"></div>
        <img src="images/home_pic_1.jpg" alt="" width="180" height="188" />
     <div class="home_sub">here is some slide in text</div>
  </div>
```

**css**

```
   #home_1 {position:absolute; overflow:hidden; top:82px;}


    .home_overlay {position:absolute; background:#fff; display:none;}
    .home_sub {
    width:150px;
    height:50px;
    background:blue;
    position:absolute;
    left: -1000px;
    top: 70px;
}
```

**javascript**

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
 $(document).ready(function() {


   $(".home_1").hover(
      function () {
    var img = $(this).children('img');
        $(".home_overlay",this).height(img.height());
        $(".home_overlay",this).width(img.width());
        $(".home_overlay",this).fadeTo('slow', 0.5);
        $(".home_sub",this).css('left',img.width());
        $(".home_sub",this).css('top',(img.height()/2)-25);
        varNewPos = img.width() - 150 +"px"
        //alert(varNewPos);
        $(".home_sub",this).animate({left:varNewPos});
      }, 
      function () {
$(".home_overlay",this).fadeOut(fast);
              }
   );

 });
</script>
```

The mouseover bit works fine but on mouseout nothing happens. Then I found that using

```
$(".home_overlay",this).css('display','none');
```

worked. So did changing any other css propoerties but fadeOut and other jquery animations failed to fire.

What am I doing wrong?

cheers

dog

Comment: Welcome aboard the stackoverflow.com party boat!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make:

```
$(".home_overlay",this).fadeOut(fast);
```

be

```
$(".home_overlay",this).fadeOut('fast');
```

EDIT: Just noticed that `$(".home_1")` should be `$("#home_1")` also

Comment: well, there you go... it was a stupid typo on my part... because it was failing at the 'fast' bit then it wasn't executing the following jquery which slid out the overlay...
thank you very much for the pointer :)

Comment: @Dog, site tip: click the checkmark next the the answer to mark the question as answered for folks when you are satisfied with an answer - will show a green checkmark after :)